# Access the uploaded image file from models.imagefield in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to process the image before saving it while uploading from `models.ImageField(upload_to=None)` but i could not be able to find the way to access the image. my code is below

```
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):
   document_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   img = models.ImageField(upload_to=None)
   some_func_value = Process_image(img)
```

In the above code `Process_image()` function expects an image file in the form of `numpy` array in its argument to process but when i pass img i.e `Process_image(img)` it gives me an error that img is not a `numpy` array. I want to find a way to access the image to process it  before saving it.

Also what is returned by `models.ImageField()` in other words what is the type of img variable in above code? is there anyway to access an image from img variable

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this sort of thing in the model definition and I can't see why you have tried to do so. An actual image doesn't exist until the user uploads one, there is no point calling `Process_image` at *definition* time.

You should do this in the form or view that handles the actual upload.